# Are there any online tools that allow you to figure out the names of the industry positions you should look for?

Tags: job-search

I am almost done with my PhD in physics (specifically, in MRI), and I am not sure which positions would fit me well. I am also not very familiar with the terminology used in the industry, so I am unsure which search terms to use. I am not asking SA to recommend me a job, but I do wonder if there's any tools or resources that could help in browsing the job market effectively.

My main question is thus: are there any online tools that allow you to figure out the names of the positions you should look for, based either on your preferences and your hard skills?

To illustrate the sort of things I would like to get recommended by some online tool, here are the positions I have looked for (and done interviews for) so far:

- research engineer
- R & D engineer
- signal processing engineer
- quantitative developer
- data scientist

As an 'analog' example -and to address the Louic's comment below- there's [Sarah Blackford's test for career choice](https://biosciencecareers.org/career-choice). Surely there must be some online tool that does similar things?

Comment: Some feedback on why this is being downvoted would be nice. I think it's a valid question. And if the answer is obvious, do let me know.

Comment: I agree that this is a shopping question, but I doubt that this will attract a lot of answers because I suspect I am looking for something quite obscure. I will not attempt to salvage this question.

Answer (score 1):

The words you are looking for are "phd physics", which when input into a jobs portal - if you don't know what these are in your local country, search using Google -  will find you all jobs that ask for applicants with a PhD in physics. You can also search Google directly with "physics phd jobs".

Comment: Somehow I thought that using that as a search term would only show me Physics PhD's, but it of course also searches the content of the job posting. Very nice suggestion!

Comment: Limiting your search to just 'physics' will be a disservice to yourself. The OP should at least try 'electrical engineering' or even just 'STEM' in there, and probably add some more specific key words for their particular skills. I post a lot of jobs where the degree could be physics, chemistry, EE, materials science, chemical engineering, ... just because the particular skills/interests of the person matter more than the title on the degree. Certain specialties end up in very different departments in different universities.

Comment: @JonCuster I think that depends on how many results one finds. If one does not find enough results with "physics phd", then one can broaden the search terms. But if there are lots of interesting results with "physics phd" then one's time would be better spent investigating those jobs than casting a wider net.

Comment: @Allure - I guess my point was that the skills and attributes of a job the OP wants are (perhaps) more important than the degree title. My job postings list required and desired attributes. A PhD in a relevant area is one of the requirements, but the stuff somebody gets excited about is in the desired listing.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google's robots have crawled the job vacancies pages of back issues of _New Scientist_ from the late 1950s and early 1960s.  That's mostly what I get when I try the equivalent of this.